# Getting an error even when selecting correct xpath to the element in selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automation, element

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='invis-o-div']"));
        
        if (!element.isDisplayed()) {
            
            question = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Practice_Question_Body']//p[1]")).getText();
            
        }
```

I am trying to get a string from the element (in the picture) using the xpath, I tried all methods but it doesn't look like any of them work, the first error I get is from the beginning where I try to get a text only when an element that covers whole screen is not displayed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

first make this `xpath` into `Array` then try to access the elements of array using `index`

```
(//div[@class='Practice_Question_Body']//p)[index]
```